# Fatal error: Cannot declare class **** because the name is already in use in　のエラーを解消できない。

Tags: php

phpでオブジェクト指向型のプログラムを実装しています。（初級者です。）
namespaceを設定してクラスの呼び出しを行っていますが、以下のエラーが解消されません。
クラス名を変えたりと色々やってますが、原因の追究ができません。
どなたか分かる方、アドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

*facilityEditController.php (Controllerまでのパス:facility/edit/)*

```
<?php
session_start();
//ディレクトリcommonまでのパス（facility/edit/common）
require('common/sqlDefinedClass.php');
require('common/pdoAceessClass.php');
require('common/commonClass.php');
require('facility_edit_model.php');
$pdo_aceess = new Edit\aceessPDO();
$sql_defind_edit = new Edit\sqlDefindEdit();
$common = new Edit\common();
$facility_edit_model = new facilityEditModel();
```

*sqlDefinedClass.php (パス:facility/edit/)*

```
<?php
  namespace Edit;

  class sqlDefind {
   function insertSql($tablename,$column,$value) {
     //sql格納用変数を初期化
     $sql = "";
     $sql .= <<< EOF
  INSERT INTO 
  EOF;<?php
  //以下、省略
```

*facilityInputController.php (Controllerまでのパス:facility/input/)*

```
<?php
session_start();
require('common/sqlDefinedClass.php');
require('common/pdoAceessClass.php');
require('common/commonClass.php');
require('facility_input_model.php');

$pdo_aceess = new Input\aceessPDO();
$sql_defind_input = new Input\sqlDefindInput();
$common = new Input\common();
$facility_input_model = new facilityModel();
```

*sqlDefinedClass.php (パス:facility/input/)*

```
<?php
  namespace Input;

  class sqlDefind {
   function insertSql($tablename,$column,$value) {
     //sql格納用変数を初期化
     $sql = "";
     $sql .= <<< EOF
  INSERT INTO 
  EOF;<?php
  //以下、省略
```

**エラー内容**

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Edit\sqlDefind, because the name is already in 
use in C:\xampp\htdocs\hoikushien\wp-content\plugins\matching_system\facility\edit\common\sqlDefinedClass.php on line 4
```

お手数おかけしますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: sqlDefinedClassを宣言する前にfunction.get-declared-classesで配列をとるとsqlDefindが宣言されていることは確認できますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
var_dump(get_declared_classes());
上記コードで確認したところ、宣言されていることを確認できました。
ただ、２回var_dumpが走っているようで、同じ結果が二つ表示されています。
このことが原因だと思いますが、なぜ２回走るのか原因が分からない状態です。

Comment: ちなみにwordpressのプラグインとして開発しています。

Comment: よくわからないがファイルが２回requireされているということであれば、debug_backtrace を利用して呼び出し元のファイルのループを確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。自分も原因が分からなったので、一からやり直したところ、エラーが解消されました。予め用意していたファイル等が邪魔していたようです。get_declared_classes()、debug_backtrace()を知ることができて、大変助かりました。今後に役立てたいと思います。ありがとうございました。